# Sails JS - Deep populate of the same model and attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, sails.js, populate

Let me explain it a little bit. The idea is to have categories and each category can have a parent category and a subcategory as well, but we don't know how deep this tree can go. For Example:

```
->Clothes
-->Men
--->Kids
---->Newborns
----->Etc, etc
-->Women
-->Unisex
```

So I thought that my Category.js model could have these attributes:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    products: {
      collection: 'product',
      via: 'category'
    },
    parentCategory: {
      model: 'category'
    },
    subCategories: {
      collection: 'category',
      via: 'parentCategory'
    }
  }
};
```

And when I get all my categories:

```
Category.find({}).populate('subCategories').exec(........
```

I get a list of all categories and its subcategories, but I also want to have the subcategories of the subcategories, just like the tree hierarchy I wrote before, but instead I'm getting

Clothes { subCategories: [Men:{}, Women:{}, Unisex:{}] }
Men { .....

But inside of Clothes, I have Men, that's correct. But now inside of this Men object I don't have "Kids".

Am I being clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate method only works in one level (at the moment), so you can't populate and object and then populate other one inside. I had a similar feature and I found and wrote this code, maybe it can help you:

```
  return Object.findOne({
        id: id
      }).populateAll().then(function (result) {
         var otherObject= otherObject.find(result.id).then(function (otherResult) {
           return otherResult;
         });
         return [result, otherResult];
      }).spread(function (house, otherResult) {
         result= result.toObject();
         result.otherResult= otherResult;
         return result;
      });
```